# How would one translate "swag"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

Since *swag* generally means the coolness of a person (e.g. *I have swag*, *I am a swaggy person*), would *mojosegeco* or *mojoseco* be a good translation for *swag*?

Comment: Mmh. I know 'swag' as a term for free stuff you get eg at a conference, such as bags, pens, and other things. Never come across it in this meaning before.

Comment: @OliverMason Really? Interesting :D I've only ever heard it in the sense of "cool". But to me it's alsways been a slang, so I have no idea what the official meaning is, if it has one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example that could clarify the meaning. "I have swag" and "I am swaggy" only mean anything if the listener already knows what swag means -- and based on the replies, and comments, it doesn't seem like that's the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m not super hip with the lingo of today’s youth, but I’ve **heard** that *swag* comes from *swagger*, which is a verb that is translated to Esperanto as *paradi* or *pavi* (literally “to peacock”). If you wanted to maintain that connotation, you could use *parademo*/*pavemo*, *paradeco*/*paveco*, ktp. That implies a degree of arrogance that the word *swagger* carries.

Otherwise, *mojosa* seems to be the catch-all for positive slang terms. Lernu lists 'cool', 'awesome', 'groovy', 'radical', and 'epic'. To turn that into a noun, you would use *mojoseco*.

Answer (score 3):

Very simplified, *swag* has two meanings

- cool
- not cool (because it is forced)

depending on context. Therefore, I would translate *swaggy* into *mojosa* or *mojosaĉa/malmojosa* depending on which of the two meanings is the intended.

Comment: Since _mojosa_ is an acronym from _moderna juna stila_, the opposite is _malmoderna maljuna stila_ (a.k.a. auntie style) or _momosa_.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're piling slang upon slang and the expense of clarity.

Urban dictionary defines "swag" as... well... as a word that respectable people don't use. (Their definition was much more colorful than my summary here.) On top of that *mojosa* is widely overused - especially by new learners and anglophones who don't understand that "cool" means many more things in the English speaking world than it does in the worlds of the other languages which have borrowed this word.

Take a look in a thesaurus and find another word for the idea you're trying to express with "swag" and ask about that. It would help if you put it in context.